# Выделение памяти в си (более 4Гб)

Tags: c

1. Объяснте, как (почему) это работает?

Естественно ни оперативки ни даже жёсткого диска такого размера у меня нет.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  size_t d[500000000000 + 1];
    
  d[0] = 10;
  d[5000000] = 20;
  d[50000000] = 30;
  d[500000000] = 40;
  d[5000000000] = 50;
  d[50000000000] = 60;
  d[500000000000] = 70;

  printf("elements=%llu, size=%llu\n", sizeof(d)/sizeof(size_t), sizeof(d));
  printf("d[0]=%llu\n",               d[0]);
  printf("d[5.000.000]=%llu\n",       d[5000000]);
  printf("d[50.000.000]=%llu\n",      d[50000000]);
  printf("d[500.000.000]=%llu\n",     d[500000000]);
  printf("d[5.000.000.000]=%llu\n",   d[5000000000]);
  printf("d[50.000.000.000]=%llu\n",  d[50000000000]);
  printf("d[500.000.000.000]=%llu\n", d[500000000000]);
  
  return 0;
}
```

вывод:

```
elements=500000000001, size=4000000000008 
d[0]=10 
d[5.000.000]=20
d[50.000.000]=30 
d[500.000.000]=40 
d[5.000.000.000]=50
d[50.000.000.000]=60 
d[500.000.000.000]=70
```

собираю так: (x64)

```
gcc.exe -m64 test.c -O3 -o test.exe
```

2. Можно ли выделить блок памяти более 4Гб (в 64 битном приложении)?

Как это правильно работает в си? (malloc больше не может, как я понял)

Comment: Про выделение памяти, может, кто-нибудь другой ответит, но вы можете посмотреть эти вопросы: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2798330/7485582 и https://stackoverflow.com/q/19367881/7485582. Если кратко, то ограничения в 4 ГБ для 64-битных приложений нет.

Comment: Сейчас в ОСях используется виртуальная память. Так что можно выделить памяти столько, сколько позволит ОСь, и от того какой у тебя большой своп. Она, кстати, не обязана её реально выделять, пока ты не будешь эту выделенную память реально использовать. Я когда экспериментровал, в цикле выделил столько памяти, сколько у меня даже на SSD нет =)

Comment: Что касается оптимизаций, то есть такое понятие как *[не]наблюдаемое поведение*. Если компилятор докажет, что разницы в результатах ты не заметишь, а производительность вырастет, то он может сделать много на первый взгляд странных и далеко не очевидных вещей.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

У вас стоит опция `-O3`. Компилятор понимает, что массив на самом деле тут не нужен и производит оптимизацию, просто подставляя в вывод константы.

```
.LC0:
        .string "elements=%llu, size=%llu\n"
.LC1:
        .string "d[0]=%llu\n"
.LC2:
        .string "d[5.000.000]=%llu\n"
.LC3:
        .string "d[50.000.000]=%llu\n"
.LC4:
        .string "d[500.000.000]=%llu\n"
.LC5:
        .string "d[5.000.000.000]=%llu\n"
.LC6:
        .string "d[50.000.000.000]=%llu\n"
.LC7:
        .string "d[500.000.000.000]=%llu\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        movabs  rdx, 4000000000008
        movabs  rsi, 500000000001
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 20
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 30
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC3
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 40
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC4
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 50
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC5
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 60
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC6
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 70
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC7
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oh3c8T

Без этой опции память будет выделяться. Скорее всего, при выполнении такого кода программа аварийно завершится.

https://godbolt.org/z/8a9baM

Comment: А что происходит тут: `movabs  rdx, 4000000000008` `movabs  rsi, 500000000001`?

Comment: @wololo, посмотрите на вывод. Это параметры массива, которые выводятся. Фактически компилятор массив убрал, но sizeof всё равно должен отработать корректно, так как оптимизации компилятора не должны влиять на работу программы, если нет UB.

Comment: Действительно, я на первый `prinf` не обратил внимания.

Comment: Прикольно, оно так и выглядело, как какая-то виртуализация, т.к. в цикле это уже не работало, но правильный размер массива смущал) жестокий оптимизатор!

Comment: И за еxplorer отдельное спасибо, очень удобно